# Git checkout to discard changes

Tags: git, git-checkout

I am trying to discard all my local changes and it seems that after I type

`$ git checkout -- .`

.. changes seem to still be there...

If I try:

`$ git checkout HEAD .`

.. it works, changes are discarded!

Why is this happening? Any ideas?

Hint: The changes seem to be relevant to line endings, as no real content was actually edited (that is why I needed to discard after all)

**Update**: I use Git 1.9.5 for windows.
My local changes are unstaged, uncommited, just under the workingtree

Comment: What version of Git are you using? I just tested `git checkout -- .`, and it did discard my changes?.

Comment: Correct.. I updated my question.. :)

Comment: Can you check with Git 2.4.6? (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/)

Comment: As i see it, currently it is a pre-release.. I d prefer not to...

Comment: You can test: no setup required, just unzip the archive wherever you want

Comment: @cnom, have you commited, staged  or are your local changes in the workingtree only?

Comment: I should state that as well, right, my changes are unstaged, uncommited, they are just in the workingtree

Answer (score 1):

After I upgraded to

> git version 2.11.1.windows.1

this stopped happening (maybe an earlier version - bettween 1.9.5 and 2.11.1 - had already solved this issue)